# SQL max on date not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return the row with the latest maturity date and where there are matches for a maturity date, I would then return the record where the price is highest. However, it looks like the grouping is incorrect in my code and I'm unsure as to what the issue is.

## Query

```
SELECT
    dap.CompanyID AS CompanyId,
    MAX(dap.Price) AS Price,
    dap.AssetClass,
    dap.AsOfDate,
    MAX(dap.MaturityDate) AS MaturityDate
FROM TA.DailyAssetPricing dap WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE dap.AssetClass = 'Bond' AND dap.MaturityDate IS NOT NULL AND dap.AsOfDate = '2018-02-02' AND dap.CompanyID = 59303
GROUP BY dap.CompanyID, dap.AssetClass, dap.AsOfDate, dap.MaturityDate
```

## Results

```
CompanyId   Price   AssetClass  AsOfDate    MaturityDate
59303   106.6080860000  Bond    2018-02-02  2021-12-01 00:00:00.000
59303   97.2326750000   Bond    2018-02-02  2033-09-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Do you want the highest price for that maturity date only?  The answer from jarlh will return the highest price period not just for the max maturity date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically `GROUP BY` the selected columns, except those who are arguments to set functions.

In this case:

```
GROUP BY dap.CompanyID, dap.AssetClass, dap.AsOfDate
```

Comment: That was so obvious, thank you very much. Group by takes a distinct on the column so by having maturity date in the group clause, it would obviously return both records. Mental block; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows with the maximum maturity date, you don't need `group by`.  You can do:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES dap.*
FROM TA.DailyAssetPricing dap
WHERE dap.AssetClass = 'Bond' AND dap.MaturityDate IS NOT NULL AND
      dap.AsOfDate = '2018-02-02' AND dap.CompanyID = 59303
ORDER BY dap.MaturityDate DESC;
```